# How to cancel a function if event occurs again in jquery javascript

Tags: jquery

When I mouseenter to an element, I want to  run a function and when mouseout that element, then I want to wait for 2 seconds and if mouseenter to that element again then do nothing  else run an other function.... my code

```
$(element).on('mouseover mouseout', function (event) {
    if(event.type == 'mouseenter') {
        $('.item').css('background', 'red');
    } else {
        setTimeout(function (){
           // may be here I want to wait and if mouseenter again to that element, I want the background of item to red and after 2 seconds background goes to green.

            $('.item').css('background', 'green');
        }, 2000);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why you're combining events and then checking within? Why not use two events? And you can cancel timeouts. Is this what you were thinking?

```
var myTimeout = null;

$(element).on('mouseenter', function (event) {
    clearTimeout(myTimeout);
    $('.item').css('background', 'red');
})
$(element).on('mouseleave', function (event) {
    myTimeout = setTimeout(function (){
        $('.item').css('background', 'green');
    }, 2000);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout gives you an ID, with which you can later cancel it.. Something like this might work:

```
$(element).on('mouseover mouseout', function (event) {
    if(event.type == 'mouseenter') {
        $('.item').css('background', 'red');
        if (element.timerId) { 
            clearTimeout(element.timerId);
            element.timerId = null;
        }
    } else {
        if (element.timerId) 
            clearTimeout(element.timerId);
        element.timerId = setTimeout(function (){
            $('.item').css('background', 'green');
            element.timerId = null;
        }, 2000);
    }
})
```